# RockMongo, "Unable to load dynamic library '/.../mongo.so' - wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown"

Tags: apache, mongodb, lampp

I just installed [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo) by extracting all the files to a lampp web folder `/opt/lampp/htdocs/rockMongo/`. Visiting index.php shows

> To make things right, you must install php_mongo module. [Here for
>   installation documents on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php).

I followed the instructions there (I had to install `php-pear`):

> - sudo pecl install mongo
> - Add the following line to php.ini: extension=mongo.so

Now, when I start the web server (apache), I get the following warning, repeated **hundreds** of times:

> Warning: PHP Startup: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
>   'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in Unknown on line 0

and also this warning a single time:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mongo.so:
>   wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0

The index page stills shows the same message (which means that `class_exists("Mongo")` returns false)

I tried putting in the absolute path to mongo.so, but that didn't do anything. What's going on?

**edit:** I used

```
$ file /usr/bin/php5
/usr/bin/php5: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

which seems to suggest my php installation is 64 bits, yet when I print out `PHP_INT_MAX` I get `2147483647` which seems to indicate my installation is 32 bits. How can I know the "bitness" of my php installation?

Answer (score 0):

From the second PHP warning, it looks like you've mixed 32bit code and a 64bit library.

Make sure all the stuff you've downloaded is of the same "bitness" as your PHP installation.

Comment: Does that ELF class mean that mongo.so is 64 bits? I'm still trying to figure out whether my lampp installation is 64 bits, can't quite figure it out yet.

Comment: Find the `php` executable and run `file /path/to/php`. It will tell you if it's 32bit or 64bit. The `mongo.so` file does appear to be a 64bit ELF.

Comment: $ file /usr/bin/php5
->
/usr/bin/php5: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

Comment: Both PHP5 and mongo.so seem to be 64 bits

Comment: Do you have any other files in /usr/lib/php5/20090626? Is your LAMP not using a php interpreter installed in /opt/lamp?

Comment: I also have /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo.so but I don't need it. Would it help to delete it? I don't know about a php interpreted in /opt/lampp.. /opt/lampp contains the following: backup  bin  cgi-bin  error  etc  htdocs  icons  lampp  lib  libexec  licenses  logs  modules  phpmyadmin  phpsqliteadmin  RELEASENOTES  sbin  share  tmp  var

Comment: Look at the "bitness" of the files inside `lib` and `libexec`, and at what's in `lampp`. Look at the bitness of that `pdo.so`. Look at other files/directories under /usr/lib*/php5.

Comment: How can I check the "bitness" of files?

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused about the "bitness" of my php installation, see my edit.